# Add single quotes to the dataFrame column values

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

`DataFrame` is holding a column `QUALIFY` with values like below.

```
QUALIFY
=================
ColA|ColB|ColC
ColA
ColZ|ColP
```

The values in this column are split by `"|"`. I want values in this column to be like `'ColA','ColB','ColC' ...`

With the below code I am able to replace `|` with `,',`. How can I add a single quote at the start and end of value?

```
newDf = df_qualify.withColumn('QUALIFY2', regexp_replace('QUALIFY', "\\|", "\\','"))
```

Comment: Why don't you first split it on `|` and then join the resulting array back to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is almost there - you just need to add a single quote to the start and end. You can achieve this using [`pyspark.sql.functions.concat`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat, lit, regexp_replace

df.withColumn(
    "QUALIFY2",
    concat(lit("'"), regexp_replace(col('QUALIFY'), r"\|", r"','"), lit("'"))
).show()
#+--------------+--------------------+
#|       QUALIFY|            QUALIFY2|
#+--------------+--------------------+
#|ColA|ColB|ColC|'ColA','ColB','ColC'|
#|          ColA|              'ColA'|
#|     ColZ|ColP|       'ColZ','ColP'|
#+--------------+--------------------+
```

Alternatively, you can avoid regular expressions and achieve the same using [`split`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) and [`concat_ws`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, concat_ws
df.withColumn(
    "QUALIFY2", 
    concat(lit("'"), concat_ws("','", split("QUALIFY", "\|")), lit("'"))
).show()
#+--------------+--------------------+
#|       QUALIFY|            QUALIFY2|
#+--------------+--------------------+
#|ColA|ColB|ColC|'ColA','ColB','ColC'|
#|          ColA|              'ColA'|
#|     ColZ|ColP|       'ColZ','ColP'|
#+--------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the column on `|` and then join the resulting array back to a string :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

def str_list(x):
    return str(x).replace("[", "").replace("]", "")

str_udf = F.udf(str_list, T.StringType())

df = df.withColumn("arr_split", F.split(F.col("QUALIFY"), "\|")) # escape character
df = df.withColumn("QUALIFY2", str_udf(F.col("arr_split")))
```

My sample output frame:

```
df.drop("arr_split").show() # Please ignore a and b columns
+---+---+--------------+--------------------+
|  a|  b|           abc|            QUALIFY2|
+---+---+--------------+--------------------+
|  1|  1|col1|col2|col3|'col1', 'col2', '...|
|  2|  2|col1|col2|col3|'col1', 'col2', '...|
|  3|  3|col1|col2|col3|'col1', 'col2', '...|
|  4|  4|col1|col2|col3|'col1', 'col2', '...|
|  5|  5|col1|col2|col3|'col1', 'col2', '...|
+---+---+--------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me, added the square brackets back to make it an array
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

```
    def str_list(x):
        return str(x).replace("[", "").replace("]", "")

    str_udf = F.udf(str_list, T.StringType())

    df = df.withColumn(column_name,str_udf(F.col(column_name)))
    df = df.withColumn(column_name, F.expr("concat('[', " + column_name +", ']')"))
```